# Removing the PopupLogger in GWT 2.7.0

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.7

I've recently upgrade my web-app to GWT 2.7, in which the PopupLogger has apparently been removed.

I've never used this so it's been disabled in my gwt.xml, but now you have to remove that property from your gwt.xml to compile.

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
```

But now the damn thing appears for a few seconds every-time the page loads, as below, even though it's not supposed to exist. Has anyone seen this / have any idea how to get rid of it?

[image]

My logging configuration is now:

```
<!-- Enable remote / development mode logging -->
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler"    value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler"          value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler"         value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.hasWidgetsHandler"      value="DISABLED" />
```

Comment: On load the application reports only three handlers: DevelopmentModeLogHandler, SystemLogHandler, and SimpleRemoteLogHandler, yet the popup still appears.

Comment: It doesnt exist any more, so if you see it, you aren't fully using GWT 2.7. Make sure there isnt some leftover jar from an older version of GWT?